# xcode 5.1 beta ad hoc builds fail to upload to Test Flight

Tags: ios7, xcode5, testflight

Since upgrading to the beta release Xcode 5.1, I'm unable to submit ad hoc distribution builds to TestFlight because of the following error:

[image]

Same via the web client:

[image]

My distribution flow is the same as it was in 5.0, archive, sign with ad-hoc provisioning profile, upload to test flight. This is happening across multiple projects and teams which leads me to think it's a 5.1 issue.

Is anyone else seeing this? I'm in the process of reinstalling 5.0 to see if that helps.

Comment: I am having the same issue. My provisioning profile is ok, my ipa is being signed with the proper adhoc code signing cert. I have tried the accepted answer, but it doesn't work in my case. Anyone else having this issue still?

Comment: I am having it as well :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5.0 didn't help, but I narrowed down the issue to building archives with a physical device with iOS 7.1 beta installed as the target build target. Disconnecting the device and building against "iOS Device" results in valid builds for Ad Hoc distribution in both 5.0 and 5.1.

[image]

Perhaps something about the beta status of iOS 7.1, but anyway, hope this helps if you encountered the same thing.